# Can I use beforeunload to load a JS function

Tags: javascript

Hi There I am trying to use beforeunload (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) to run a JS function when a user lands on a page and im not too sure how to go about this.

I am trying to call a function called speechCancel but im really not too sure on how to do this any assistance would be apprechiated.

Comment: `beforeunload` doesn't fire on mobile. `visibilitychange` event may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The entire point of `beforeunload` is to run a JavaScript function when a user **is leaving** a page. Not when they land on it (which is usually handled by [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)).

Comment: sorry i didnt mean for the confusion the function needs to run either on page load or when a user is leaving which I did not mention so sorry for that. Is there a way for this to be used when a user is leaving then as I am new to JS and im not too sure how to lay this out.

Comment: @Ryan1827 — The documentation you linked to has examples. I don't see what more you need to get started. If you have made an attempt which doesn't work and you don't understand why, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about your attempt, making sure to include a [mcve].